# Hierarchical data filters in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have an issue with hierarchical filtering in shiny. The goal is to load a data.frame with columns that have some hierarchical structure (e.g. region - country) and use `selectInput()` to filter the data. Also, I need the drop-down menus to depend on each other so that the second one is only relevant to the first selection. My sample app is here:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(
  class1 = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), each = 4),
  class2 = c(rep(c("a1", "a2"), each = 2), rep(c("b1", "b2"), each = 2),
             rep(c("c1", "c2"), each = 2)),
  val = 1:12,
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    actionButton('loaddata', 'Load Data'),
    br(), br(),
    selectInput('class1', 'Class 1',
                choices = c('Select class 1' = '')),
    selectInput('class2', 'Class 2',
                choices = c('Select class 1 first' = ''))
  ),
  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput("out"),
    verbatimTextOutput("counter")
  )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  counter <- reactiveVal(0)

  data.all <- eventReactive(input$loaddata, {
    data
  })

  class1 <- reactive({
    if (input$class1 == '_All_') return('')
    else return(input$class1)
  })

  class2 <- reactive({
    if (input$class2 == '_All_') return('')
    else return(input$class2)
  })

  observe({
    class1 <- c('_All_', data.all()$class1)
    updateSelectInput(session, 'class1', choices = class1)
  })

  observe({
    if (class1() == '') {
      class2 <- c('Select class 1 first' = "")
    } else {
      class2 <- data.all() %>%
        filter(grepl(class1(), class1, fixed = T)) %>%
        .$class2 %>% c('_All_', .)
    }

    updateSelectInput(session, 'class2', choices = class2)
  })

  data.filter <- reactive({
    isolate(counter(counter() + 1))

    data.all() %>%
      filter(grepl(class1(), class1, fixed = T),
             grepl(class2(), class2, fixed = T))
  })

  output$out <- renderPrint({ data.filter() })
  output$counter <- renderPrint({ counter() })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Note: the `class1()` and `class2` reactives are there to return an empty string if `_All_` option is selected. Then it is possible to use `dplyr::filter`.

The issue is that I am running into unnecessary executions (I included a counter in the sample app). Example:

1. User selects `input$class1`
2. This triggers `class1()` reactive
3. The `class1()` triggers the `observe` with `updateSelectInput` for class 2 and also triggers `data.filter()` reactive
4. The updated `selectInput` for class 2 changes `input$class2` and triggers `class2()` reactive
5. The `class2()` reactive triggers `data.filter()` again

Similar thing is valid after switching the `selectInput` for class 1 back to `_All_`.

The question is if you can see any way this might be written in a way that the `data.filter()` reactive would "wait" until all the reactive prerequisites are ready and trigger only once.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since the second one triggers anyway as you have the `updateSelectInput` you can bind it only to the second class with `eventReactive`:

```
 data.filter <- eventReactive(class2(),{
    isolate(counter(counter() + 1))

    data.all() %>%
      filter(grepl(class1(), class1, fixed = T),
             grepl(class2(), class2, fixed = T))
  })
```